# Using TeeChart PHP with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5, teechart

I'm trying to use TeeChart PHP. I use Laravel 5.1 framework on a Ubuntu 15.04 machine. So far, I've been able to include the librairy in Laravel. I put the TeeChartPHPOpen folder into vendor, added TChart.php in Composer.json -> autoload -> files, did run `composer dumpautoload`. Also, I did install the GD extension with `sudo apt-get php5-gd` and I did restart my web server (still on artisan).

I did some tests with the Steema's demos on http://www.steema.com/products/teechart/php/demos/Features/index.html. Here are my problems:

1. With the example using JavaScript, Laravel flag me an error :

> Call to undefined method ImageExport::getJavaScript()

I looked into the ImageExport file and don't find any trace of getJavaScript function.

2. I did try another example that don't use this function (the `Axes/Custom` one). But now, there's a GD error thrown :

> FatalErrorException in GraphicsGD.php line 1275:
>   Call to undefined function imageantialias()

I can comment the imageantialias function lines (1275 and 1301) and then the example works. For now, it can do the trick but I really want to use the JavaScript asset and it be pleasant to have the anti-aliasing function too.

Any help is welcome! Thanks.

Comment: I'm trying to make TeeChart for PHP to run under an Ubuntu 15.04 virtual machine and I will share my experience here as soon as I get something usable. In the meanwhile I'd suggest you to read the discussion [here](http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=10501) when I checked it with Ubuntu 9.10

Comment: @Yeray Thanks for your help, I checked the discussion you mentioned. It's a bit old but there's a post that is close to what I experienced, but the linked solution is broken... Check your November 18, 2009 post. Maybe you can retrieve that link? Thanks again for your consideration.

Comment: Do you mean the link to *recompiling-php5-with-bundled-support-for-gd-on-ubuntu? You'll find instructions about how to do this if you search for it. Actually, I also copied from there what I did in the next posts (Nov 24 and Dec 1). But I'm not sure if recompiling php is necessary in newer versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: @Yeray I did my research and found 2 step-by-step instructions. The first is for recompiling php5 [link](https://altinukshini.wordpress.com/2011/02/19/php-gd-fix/) and the second is for adding GD librairy without recompiling php [link](http://nossie.addicts.nl/php5-gd.html), wich is from the same imageantialias() problem. In the first case, I can't recompile, InnoDB throw me an error an abort compiling. In the second case, I can't find my 5.6.4-4ubuntu6.2 version of rpm file. In your set-up, can you see the imageantialias() function?

Comment: I'm also with PHP 5.6.4-4ubuntu6.2 and I can't find the rpm for it either. I've also tried to recompile php as per those instructions without success.

Comment: The error I get when recompiling is: `debian/rules:170: recipe for target 'test-results.txt' failed
make: *** [test-results.txt] Error 141
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules build gave error exit status 2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first Error, it was my mistake, didn't read through all the documentation for the free/trial version. JavaScript isn't available for this version.

For the second one, I recompile PHP following this thread https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo

The compilation configuration that worked for me was this one :

```
./configure  --prefix=/usr/
              --with-apxs2=/usr/bin/apxs2
              --with-config-file-path=/etc/php5/apache2
              --disable-ipv6 --enable-inline-optimization
              --disable-debug
              --enable-bcmath
              --enable-calendar
              --with-curl --enable-ctype
              --enable-discard-path
              --enable-exif
              --enable-ftp
              --with-gd
              --with-freetype-dir
              --with-jpeg-dir
              --with-png-dir
              --enable-gd-native-ttf
              --enable-magic-quotes
              --enable-mbstring
              --with-mcrypt --enable-soap --with-pear --with-xsl --with-zlib --with-openssl --enable-sockets --with-mysqli --enable-zip --with-tidy=/usr/ --with-bz2
```

I'll just have buy the TeeChart to access the JavaScript translator.

Comment: I bought the commercial version and I struggled to make the simpliest example to work. There's a bug in JavaScriptExport.php, the PathToScript and PathToExtraScript must point to the latest .jss (replace v2012.09.30.1 by latest).